# About the use of [python-bin]

Tags: discussion, tags

I've seen this question pop-up to my hot page : [Binary numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523465/binary-numbers-in-python) because of an edit which was just adding [python-bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-bin) (Excerpt: *Use it for any integer to binary conversion in python.*) by a given user.

This tag, created 10 days ago, intrigued me as I didn't understood it at first and it have only 10 questions and no follower. After a little search, I find out that the tag were added, a while after the question was asked, **by the same user**.

It seems that it refers to the usage of Python [`bin(x)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bin)

Is such behavior (create a tag for the use of a function/method) intended?

Comment: Unless there are many questions about it using a specific tag can help to make it easier to find such questions. If the tag is only created because there is a method with that name I don't think it is very helpful. I can imagine those question could also be tagged [tag:python] and [tag:base-conversion] or any other [tag:conversion] variants.

Comment: It is just a habit of the [python] community, they like prefixing the language name to their contextual tags for some reason.  Most questions in the [bin] tag are already Python questions so there is very little point to it.  Retagging to [bin] is the obvious approach but it doesn't matter that much.

Comment: I suspect that the [bin] tag is abused. Or otherwise a nondescript tag that might be good for burnination.

Comment: Tag [python-bin] does not exist and I assume one of you closed it promptly 2+ years ago, can you please close this with a self-answer?